# get NSString from strftime

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, datetime

I have an SQLite database with a column called start_time. When I query the table, I select start_time in the form of `strftime('%H:%M:%S', t1.Time)` and I can get the value in a nice string using FMDB `stringForColumn`. But I need to do the conversion in code (Objective C) and cannot figure out how. The table shows values like 30, 51, 25, etc, etc...

How can I convert these time values into hours and minutes?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm probably being dense — what format are the values in the database and what are they relative to? Are you storing strings directly?

Comment: I'm not sure. Unfortunately, I'm a newbie when it comes to SQlite. When I look at the table using SQLite Manager, the type is blank.

Comment: But do the values in there look like they're meant to be the output of the `%H:%M:%S` or the input (aside: what language is the `strftime` performed in? I'm aware of the C call but you've got single quotes as string delimiters so I'm guessing not that)?

Comment: right. I create the query in Objective C and pass it to FMResultSet.

Comment: After talking to our DB guys (more than once), I finally found out what the values represented. They are keys to another table. Thanks for your help. I would love to give you the accepted answer, since you lead me to the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you store your time as an integer (see SQLite ["Date and Time Datatype"](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)). You can convert the integer using a date formatter (see ["Date Formatters"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)) or unix functions.

Using a date formatter:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [formatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

cache the constructed formatter if you use it repeatedly, then use it as follows:

```
    NSTimeInterval seconds = 465;

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"Time is: %@", dateString);
```

Or using unix functions:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <xlocale.h>

...

    time_t seconds = 465;

    struct tm tm_time;
    gmtime_r(&seconds, &tm_time);
    char buffer[9];
    strftime_l(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%H:%M:%S", &tm_time, NULL);

    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Time is: %@", dateString);
```